# Pinning a taskpane for Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane?tabs=xmlmanifest), I've added `<SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>` to my `manifest.xml`, but my task pane is still not pin-able.

My `manifest.xml` element looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>e08add90-caa6-4352-9749-c3612d8b2350</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>My Taskpane App</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Taskpane App"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="AI-Powered Email Workflows for Logistics, powered by My Taskpane App."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost"/>
    </Hosts>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="DefaultGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="taskPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.OpenLabel" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="My Taskpane App Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.OpenLabel" DefaultValue="Open My Taskpane App" />
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Open My Taskpane App" />
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

[image]

I have tested in both **Outlook Desktop App for Windows** and the **Outlook Web App**.

Comment: Hi @Nerdragen, using the manifest you shared we are able to get a pinable taskpane. Could you please check if the issue still persists for you?

Comment: Is there another setting that I would need to toggle for it to work? I installed a bunch of different add-ins and none of them allowed for a pin-able task pane either. For reference, my Outlook App build is 1.2023.1114.100 (Production), Client Version 20231124004.07. However, I also cannot get pinning to work on Outlook for the Web.

Comment: No there is no other setting other than having <SupportsPinning> set to true in the manifest.  We would need some more input from you like a code snippet or your add-in, a repro video etc. Would request you to create a new issue here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues - so that we can communicate better. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, we have added comments on this issue on GitHub.